# MLE for Overdispersed Poisson

Tags: maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution, likelihood, overdispersion

I searched for a while on Google and this website for an answer to this question.

I have an overdispersed Poisson distribution and a "hand-wavy" proof is giving me problems.

Below is the information I was given.

[image]

[image]

I have tried using the standard method to find the MLE for the Poisson distribution to arrive at the final likelihood function but I cannot get the natural log term in the final sum.
I am assuming the reason it doesn't work is that the distribution is an ODP, not just Poisson. I think I am missing something in the process.

Does anyone have any ideas? Papers?

Comment: You would obtain a similar log term for the usual Poisson distribution, suggesting your issue isn't with the over-dispersion, but with the algebraic rules of logarithms.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399613, for instance.

Comment: Perhaps if you show your work, we can explain where you went astray.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I think after I looked at it more, I took the derivative in the wrong place. The last line above $$l = sum(c_i*ln(mu_i) - mu_i)$$ $$l'=sum(c_i*1/mu_i - 1)$$ produces the estimator I am looking for. Forgive me, I haven't had to look at MLE or likelihood derivations in a while. :(

Comment: If you solved it, you can post an answer yourself (so it does not linger as unresolved)